# Java underscore - Converting JSON to XML in Java

Tags: java, underscore-java

I hope it's not a duplicated question, I was looking for an answer for my simple question but I couldn't find anyhting.
I need to convert json to xml using the underscore java library and this is quite easy using U.jsonToXml method. My problem is when I need to create node with value and attribute.

What I can do:

```
<some_root>
  <ABC some_attribute="attribute">
    <another_tag>some_value</another_tag>
  </ABC>
</some_root>
```

What I need is:

```
<some_root>
  <ABC some_attribute="attribute">some_value</ABC>
</some_root>
```

I was trying different things, playing around with arrays or with self-closing-tag, looking at the gh repo but I couldn't get the node with parameters and value:

```
"{\"ABC\":{\"-attr\":\"c\", \"value\": \"test\"}}"
"{\"ABC\":{\"-attr\":\"c\", \"-value\": \"test\"}}"
```

Is there any way to do this?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The example with XML transformation:

```
    String xml =
            "<some_root>\n"
                    + "  <ABC some_attribute=\"attribute\">\n"
                    + "    <another_tag>some_value</another_tag>\n"
                    + "  </ABC>\n"
                    + "</some_root>";
    Map<String, Object> data = U.fromXmlMap(xml);
    U.set(data, "some_root.ABC.#text", U.get(data, "some_root.ABC.another_tag"));
    U.remove(data, "some_root.ABC.another_tag");
    String newXml = U.toXml(data);
    assertEquals("<some_root>\n" +
            "  <ABC some_attribute=\"attribute\">some_value</ABC>\n" +
            "</some_root>", newXml);
```